# ApplScript to compress folder?

Tags: macos, compression, zip, applescript, directory

What is the AppleScript to compress a folder? Not let the user select a folder from the dialog but give the folder path on a string variable. The script I know compresses the folder with the full path as folder. For example: if the folder names "ABC" is in this folder location, "Applications:Data:Level" then the compressed folder will create the folder structure like this "Applications:Data:Level:ABC" and put the content. I do not want this one. The compress ApplScript must not maintain this folder structure.

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use zip, cd to the parent directory of the zipped directory first:

```
do shell script "cd /usr/share; zip /tmp/dict.zip -r dict"
```

There are no AppleScript commands for creating archives, and Archive Utility is not scriptable.